# How get more information for user spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

hello everyone I hope you're well I've been using spring boot for 7 months but now I'm in front of a wall for 1 week with oauth 2 all working as login and registration but this during when I connect the user information is not enough provided

**here is the result I get**

```
    {
  "exp": 1610236389,
  "user_name": "fiasco555",
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_USER"
  ],
  "jti": "1JQTeD5wuRG7vDkIKKg4XUgohZw",
  "client_id": "clientId",
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ]
```

I would like more information about my users here is a copy of the code

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.security.KeyPair;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;
    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private  MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(final DataSource dataSource, final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                            final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final SecurityProperties securityProperties,
                                            final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        if (tokenStore == null) {
            tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }
        return tokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
                                              final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        if (jwtAccessTokenConverter != null) {
            return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
        }

        SecurityProperties.JwtProperties jwtProperties = securityProperties.getJwt();
        System.out.println("YESS" + jwtProperties.getKeyPairAlias());
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPair(jwtProperties, keyStoreKeyFactory(jwtProperties));

        jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder).tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    private KeyPair keyPair(SecurityProperties.JwtProperties jwtProperties, KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory) {
        return keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(jwtProperties.getKeyPairAlias(), jwtProperties.getKeyPairPassword().toCharArray());
    }
@Deprecated
    private KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory(SecurityProperties.JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
        return new KeyStoreKeyFactory(jwtProperties.getKeyStore(), jwtProperties.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfiguration.java**

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ROOT_PATTERN = "/**";

    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    public ResourceServerConfiguration(final SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, ROOT_PATTERN).access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ROOT_PATTERN).access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, ROOT_PATTERN).access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, ROOT_PATTERN).access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, ROOT_PATTERN).access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");


    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        if (tokenStore == null) {
            tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(AccessJwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }
        return tokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter AccessJwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        converter.setVerifierKey(getPublicKeyAsString());
//        converter.setSigningKey(());
        return converter;
    }

    private String getPublicKeyAsString() {
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(securityProperties.getJwt().getPublicKey().getInputStream(), UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**SecurityProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("security")
public class SecurityProperties {

    private JwtProperties jwt;

    public JwtProperties getJwt() {
        return jwt;
    }

    public void setJwt(JwtProperties jwt) {
        this.jwt = jwt;
    }

    public static class JwtProperties {

        private Resource keyStore;
        private String keyStorePassword;
        private String keyPairAlias;
        private String keyPairPassword;
        private Resource publicKey;


        public Resource getKeyStore() {
            return keyStore;
        }

        public void setKeyStore(Resource keyStore) {
            this.keyStore = keyStore;
        }

        public String getKeyStorePassword() {
            return keyStorePassword;
        }

        public void setKeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword) {
            this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
        }

        public String getKeyPairAlias() {
            return keyPairAlias;
        }

        public void setKeyPairAlias(String keyPairAlias) {
            this.keyPairAlias = keyPairAlias;
        }

        public String getKeyPairPassword() {
            return keyPairPassword;
        }

        public void setKeyPairPassword(String keyPairPassword) {
            this.keyPairPassword = keyPairPassword;
        }
        public Resource getPublicKey() {
            return publicKey;
        }

        public void setPublicKey(Resource publicKey) {
            this.publicKey = publicKey;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value= DataSourceProperties.class)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    public WebSecurityConfiguration(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        if (passwordEncoder == null) {
            passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        JdbcDaoImpl jdbcDaoImpl = new JdbcDaoImpl();

        if (userDetailsService == null) {
            userDetailsService = new JdbcDaoImpl();
            ((JdbcDaoImpl) userDetailsService).setDataSource(dataSource);
        }
        return userDetailsService;
}
}
```

**Models/User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Ce champs doit être remplie")
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "fullname")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Ce champs doit être remplie")
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String fullname;
    @Column(name = "sexe")
    private String sexe;
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @Column(name = "tel", unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Ce champ doit être remplie")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^7[7860][0-9]{7}$", message = "Ce Format de n'est pas valide")
    private String tel;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    @Email(message = "Ce adresse email n'est pas valide")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Ce champ doit être remplie")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "register_at")
    Date dateRegister = new Date(new Date().getTime());
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled = true;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getSexe() {
        return sexe;
    }

    public void setSexe(String sexe) {
        this.sexe = sexe;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getDateRegister() {
        return dateRegister;
    }

    public void setDateRegister(Date dateRegister) {
        this.dateRegister = dateRegister;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

you know my problem so propose me some solutions I'm listening here to the original code [Here](https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/centralized-authorization-jwt-spring-boot2/)  (on my side I've made some modification you can compare it)

Answer (score 0):

The key point of your problem lies in the JwtAccessTokenConverter configuration in AuthorizationServerConfiguration. Its [convertAccessToken()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java) method is responsible for converting the authentication information into JWT.
The convertAccessToken() method is actually executed by the tokenConverter property whose default value is [DefaultAccessTokenConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java)

```java
public class JwtAccessTokenConverter {

    private AccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> convertAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        return tokenConverter.convertAccessToken(token, authentication);
    }
   
    //...
}
```

DefaultAccessTokenConverter calls the userTokenConverter.convertUserAuthentication() to convert Authentication to JWT attribute

```java
public class DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

    private UserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();

    public Map<String, ?> convertAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //...
response.putAll(userTokenConverter.convertUserAuthentication(authentication.getUserAuthentication()));
        //...
        return resposne;
    }
}
```

DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter will convert username and authorities into JWT attributes which is the real reason that only user_name and authorities can find in your jwt token.

```java
public class DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter {

    public Map<String, ?> convertUserAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        response.put(USERNAME, authentication.getName());
        if (authentication.getAuthorities() != null && !authentication.getAuthorities().isEmpty()) {
            response.put(AUTHORITIES, AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities()));
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now everything is clear, create your own UserAuthenticationConverter implementation and configure it in AuthorizationServerConfiguration. this is an implementation of mine for your reference

```java
public class SubjectAttributeUserTokenConverter extends DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> convertUserAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        response.put("name", authentication.getName());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Map<String, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user), Map.class);
            response.putAll(map);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (authentication.getAuthorities() != null) {
            response.put(AUTHORITIES, AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities()));
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair());
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new SubjectAttributeUserTokenConverter());
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

By the way, spring security oauth2 project is in maintenance mode. Most of its functions such as Oauth2 ResourceServer and Oauth2 Client have been implemented in spring security that is preferable. For more details, please refer to [OAuth 2.0 Features Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix)